# WebView2 - SSO, Recognize Login, or Persist Cookies/Identity

Tags: authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, webview2

I am running into an issue, working win WebView2 in a WPF application.

The one complaint we are getting from users is that the MS login gets 'forgotten' after the browser window closes, requiring that they login via a popup MS window on subsequent webview loads, and click on their identity. If a webview2 app that has already stored the user identity is open, it seems to reuse that authentication.

Is there a way to persist that login, so that after the window closes, subsequent windows reuse that login, along with maybe an expiration on the file(s) that have that information?

Some thoughts:

- Prevent the deletion of the files providing identity
- Launching and hiding a window that would persist the identity (very old-school)
- Find a parameter that enables it to login automatically

I've already tried setting the environment variable for AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount, but that didn't work.

It is using Fixed Binaries, so passing a relative path.

```
var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions(default, default, default, true);
string installPath = @"./Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.91.0.864.48.x86";
CoreWebView2Environment env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(installPath, userFolder, options);
 
await this.webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
```

Comment: From the WebView2 point of view, all browser state is stored in the user data folder (your `userFolder` parameter in your code above). As long as you use the same folder from a previous WebView2 instance and a new WebView2 instance you should get the same behavior as in the browser if you logged in, closed the browser all the way down and then opened a new browser window.

Comment: But that is not what is happening. I am setting the user folder, and it is the users local folder. As long as one window with a previous login is open, the authentication just works, but if I close the first instance of the window, and then open a new window, it requires the user click on their identity to login. Closing the window deletes the files that were stored for authentication. At this point I wonder how I might prevent the deletion.

Comment: Right, this is why I was replying with a comment because I can answer regarding WebView2 but I don't know how your site is doing auth. If the site is using session cookies, the cookies only lasts for as long as that browsing session. Once all the windows/webview2s are gone the session is over and the cookie is deleted. If this is what is happening it may be possible to read the session cookie via the CoreWebView2.CookieManager when closing, store it somewhere else, and then write the session cookie back on startup. But I'm only guessing at why the auth session ends.

Comment: Although I think you are correct in how the control/app should work, the issue is with our SharePoint Online sites and O365 authentication. The solution I'm working on, which solves most of the problem, is using SendKeys and/or Windows API-related code to simulate user actions like entering emails address, hitting enter, or left clicking on a form.

Comment: That SendKeys work is not as solid as I'd like, so investigating Azure AD and SSO, to see I can allow the app to authenticate without user login.

Comment: Pretty sure David has guessed your problem.  You can check it by using edge with restore previous sessions checked. Now when open authenticate and close and then open again all is remembered. Webview2 does not have this setting. Earning some cookies will needed to be saved by you.